# Is there a difference between scipy.pi, numpy.pi, or math.pi?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, pi

In a project using SciPy and NumPy, when should one use `scipy.pi` vs `numpy.pi` vs just `math.pi`? Is there a difference between these values?

Comment: It's because you don't always use all of them, and you'd not want to install and import a module just to get Pi.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy
>>> math.pi == np.pi == scipy.pi
True
```

So it doesn't matter, they are all the same value.

The only reason all three modules provide a `pi` value is so if you are using just one of the three modules, you can conveniently have access to pi without having to import another module. They're not providing different values for pi.

Comment: All other things being equal, I would use `math.pi` simply because it is in the standard library if the module doesn't depend on `numpy` or `scipy` otherwise -- But as you say, use pi in whichever module you're importing to begin with because they're all the same value.

Comment: If you're already using numpy use `np.pi`, but it doesn't make sense to import NumPy just for `pi` when it's in `math`.

Answer (score 50):

One thing to note is that not *all* libraries will use the same meaning for pi, of course, so it never hurts to know what you're using. For example, the symbolic math library Sympy's representation of pi is not the same as math and numpy:

```
import math
import numpy
import scipy
import sympy

print(math.pi == numpy.pi)
> True
print(math.pi == scipy.pi)
> True
print(math.pi == sympy.pi)
> False
```

Comment: sympy Pi isn't stored as a constant/float, it's an object that contains the constant

Comment: sympy's is exactly pi, represented symbolically, for doing symbolic math.  the others are floating point approximations for doing floating point math.

Comment: `math.pi == float(sympy.pi)` return `True`

Answer (score 5):

If we look its [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/1c38ce56f2af760459bfa27ce53ca53764d2ea5d/scipy/constants/_constants.py#L69), `scipy.pi` is precisely `math.pi`; in fact, it's defined as

```py
import math as _math
pi = _math.pi
```

In their source codes, `math.pi` is [defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a5b4736e548fc5827c3bcf1a14193f77e1a989d/Include/pymath.h#L14) to be equal to `3.14159265358979323846` and `numpy.pi` is [defined](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/16413dc0092544ee36e57e431fef4624214b9114/numpy/_core/include/numpy/npy_math.h#L77) to be equal to `3.141592653589793238462643383279502884`; both are well above the 15 digit accuracy of a float in Python, so it doesn't matter which one you use.

That said, if you're not already using numpy or scipy, importing them just for `np.pi` or `scipy.pi` would add unnecessary dependency while `math` is a Python standard library, so there's not dependency issues. For example, for `pi` in tensorflow code in python, one could use `tf.constant(math.pi)`.