# How to translate a simple MATLAB equation to Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I need to understand how I can translate these few lines of MATLAB code. I don't understand how to create a vector `n1` of `n` elements and how to fill it using the same formula as in MATLAB.

Here's the MATLAB code:

```
nc = 200; ncmax = 600; dx = 0.15e-04; 
r = (dx/2):dx:dx*(ncmax+3); 
n1(1:nc) =(1 ./ (s.*sqrt(2*pi).*r(1:nc))).*exp(-((log(r(1:nc)) - med).^2)./(2*s^2));
```

I have the following in Python, but `n1` is always an empty array of `nc` elements:

```
import numpy as np

r =np.arange((dx/2),(dx*(ncmax+3)),dx)
count=1
n1=np.empty(nc)

while (count<nc)

n1[count]=(1/(s*np.sqrt(2*pi)*r[count]))*np.exp(-((np.log(r[count]))-med)**2)/(2*s**2)
count=count+1
```

Comment: 1. you are missing `:` in yout `while` statement. 2. what is `s`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a beautifully vectorized solution in MATLAB. One of the main reason for using NumPy is that it also allows for vectorization - so you shouldn't be introducing loops.

As suggested in comments by lucianopaz, there is a [guide to NumPy for MATLAB users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) which explains differences and similarities between the two. It further has a nice list of MATLAB functions and their NumPy equivalents. This may be of great help, when translating MATLAB programs.

Some hints and comments:

- Use the NumPy versions of all functions, i.e. `np.sqrt`, 
  `np.exp` (as you were previously) and `np.power` (instead of `**`). These functions can be called in a vectorized fashion, just like in MATLAB.
- As noticed by @Elisha, you are missing the definitions of `s` and `med`, so I'll just assume these are scalars, and set them to `1`.
- Instead of importing `math` just for the `math.pi`, you can also use  `np.pi`, which is [exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12645547/4221706).
- You are creating a large `r` vector and only use the first `nc` elements. Why not make `r` only of size `nc` from the start, as shown below?

Resulting NumPy code:

```
import numpy as np

nc = 200
ncmax = 600
dx = 0.15e-04
s = 1
med = 1

r = np.arange(dx / 2, dx * nc, dx)

n1 = 1 / (s * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * r) * \
     np.exp(-np.power(np.log(r) - med, 2) /
            (2 * np.power(s, 2)))
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would recommend you add a link to the [numpy for matlab users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) somewhere. It may be a good resource for @Giuseppe to read.

Comment: Great idea, @lucianopaz - this guide has helped me a lot in the past.

Answer (score 0):

you have several problems.

1. `pi` should be `math.pi` (after you add `import math`)
2. add `:` to your while line: `while (count < nc):`
3. `s` and `med` are not defined in the scope you wrote